# Holding down left mouse button and clicking right mouse button autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want a script where holding left mouse button and clicking right runs a keyboard shortcut ctrl+win+right arrow (switching desktops to right) and vice versa. How could i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 ; switch to next virtual desktop
~LButton & RButton::SendEvent {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Right down}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}{Right up}

; switch to previous virtual desktop
~RButton & LButton::SendEvent {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Left down}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}{Left up}
```